# how to declare nullable list

Tags: list, kotlin, null, nullable

i have to declare a class parameter of type nullable list(contaning String) with list default value= null

```
data class Riga(
var frase1 : List?<String>= null
)
```

this is raising:

```
Property getter or setter expected 

One type argument expected for interface List<out E>
```

Comment: You have to define the type (`List<String>`), then add a question mark (`?`) to the end. `List<String>?` look at the [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)  documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var frase1 : List<String>? = null
```